# Thread runtime error - Qt Timers cannot be stopped from another thread - MinGW

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt, mingw, qtimer

I have a GUI application made in Qt 5.7 and Qt Creator, in which two buttons call two different functions in the code:
Inside MainWindow constructor:

```
connect(button1, SIGNAL(buttonClickedForBattle(Ally*,Enemy&)), this, SLOT(attack(Ally*,Enemy&)));
connect(button2, SIGNAL(buttonClickedForBattle(Ally*,Enemy&)), this, SLOT(fire(Ally*,Enemy&)));
```

My two slots are exactly the same, except a little function call inside (to calculate damage) that differs, and a different sound when triggered.

The problem occurs only in the "fire" slot which is as follows:

```
void MainWindow::fire(Ally *a, Enemy &e)
{
    ...
    sound->play();
    ...

    system.fira(*a, e); // calculates and applies damage

    if(e.getHP() == 0)
    {
        ...
    }
    else
    {
        timer1 = new MyTimer("PrepareCounterAttackTimer", e, a);
        connect(timer1, SIGNAL(timeoutNowAttack(Enemy&,Ally*)), timer1, SLOT(stopAndBlock2(Enemy&,Ally*)));
        connect(timer1, SIGNAL(timeoutNowAttack(Enemy&,Ally*)), this, SLOT(PrepareCounterAttack(Enemy&,Ally*)));
        timer1->start(2000);
        cout << "timer started" << endl;
    }
```

The program executes the whole function ("timer started" appears) but never reached the end of "timer1", so it never enters the "PrepareCounterAttack" slot. The other slot is meant to stop the timer and block signals (I use other timers afterwards); removing its line doesn't change the result. At execution, when "button2" is clicked, a pop-up instantly appears above the GUI:

```
Runtime Error!
R6016 
- not enough space for thread data
```

And when I click on "OK" I get the following output:

```
QObject::~QObject: Timers cannot be stopped from another thread
```

FYI, this timer is of type "MyTimer", which is a subclass of QTimer:
Header file:

```
class MyTimer : public QTimer
{
   Q_OBJECT

public:
   MyTimer();
   MyTimer(std::string name, Enemy & en, Ally* al);
   ~MyTimer();

private:
   std::string name;
   Ally* ally;
   Enemy enemy;

signals:
   void mytimeout();
   void timeoutNowAttack(Enemy & en, Ally* al);

public slots:
   void stopAndBlock();

protected:
   void timerEvent(QTimerEvent* e);
};
```

Cpp file:

```
MyTimer::MyTimer()
        :QTimer()
    {
        setSingleShot(true);
    }

    MyTimer::MyTimer(string n, Enemy & en, Ally* al)
        :QTimer()
    {
        setSingleShot(true);
        name = n;
        ally = al;
        enemy = en;
    }

    MyTimer::~MyTimer()
    {
    }

    void MyTimer::timerEvent(QTimerEvent* e)
    {
        if(e->timerId() == this->timerId())
        {
            emit mytimeout();
            emit timeoutNowAttack(enemy, ally);
        }
    }

    void MyTimer::stopAndBlock()
    {
        blockSignals(true);
        stop();
    }
```

What I don't understand is:

- Why is there a thread problem while I never created one explicitly?
- Why is QObject destructor called?
- How come the runtime error occurs in *button2*'s slot but not in
  *button1*'s? The if/else part is literally the same!

I'm not proficient in multithreading and this is my first big Qt program.

**Important note:** The problem **only** occurs in

- Windows (on Linux, everything's fine)
- 32-bit MinGW (when I switch to 64-bit MSVC 2013, the slot is executed until the end)

Is it a 32-bit vs 64-bit issue?
Thank you for any ideas.

Comment: Do you know if `QObject::blockSignals` blocks the current signal (if there is one) or just future signals?  (I checked the [docs.](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#blockSignals) but didn't see anything definitive.)